# website for iphone css media queries

Tags: iphone, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am trying to fit my website for iphone 
for that i am using twitter bootstrap responsive css
i gave the container with different border colors for different width
but when i minimize the browser window the border colors are not reflecting for the browser window

http://jsfiddle.net/CXkQp/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/CXkQp/1/embedded/result/

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row {
    margin-left: -30px;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  .row:before,
  .row:after {
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
    content: "";
  }
  .row:after {
    clear: both;
  }
  [class*="span"] {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  .container,
  .navbar-static-top .container,
  .navbar-fixed-top .container,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
    width: 1170px;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the page example you posted should be responsive, though I'm not sure that your bootstrap grid is setup the way you need it.

You have nested container divs for one thing @ lines 120 and 145

Check what happens if I rename your 2 container divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/CXkQp/3/embedded/result/

http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/CXkQp/3/

line 120

```
 <div class="containerA" style="background-color: white;">
```

line 145

```
 <div class="containerB">
```

There are also some [validation errors](http://bit.ly/Zq3s8J) which could possibly be another piece of the puzzle. The cause may be that you can't simply paste HTML head content into the jsFiddle HTML panel as you have done. Check http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/hacks.html#css-panel-hack for details on what you need to do.

My appologies if I've misunderstood something

Good luck!